# How to include c #ifdef variables in defconfig

Tags: c, linux-kernel, makefile

So I am running making a defconfig before building the kernel. I am trying to use a `#ifdef` in some kernel code such that if the user chose making the first defconfig it would consider check #ifdef (value defined in defconfig) vs calling a second defconfig. Is this possible?

**Edit:** So my defconfigs are in subdirectories. I want to either call make `first_defconfig` or `second_defconfig`. Then I run `make`, based on that I would like it to be the case where if `first_defconfig` is called then `-DVARIABLEX` which should apply to the source tree not just subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible

you need to add any new config in defconfig like this way

```
CONFIG_STACKOVERFLOW=y
```

Now in any kconfig file of the kernel you should have

```
config STACKOVERFLOW
   bool "stackoverfloe flag"
   default n
```

and in code you can use this way

```
#ifdef CONFIG_STACKOVERFLOW

//do this and that

#endif
```

Comment: Hi Mr.32, the issue here is that my defconfig resides in a subdirectory. So if I do that, how would I modify the main Makefile?

Comment: @Buffalo if you have defined CONFIG_DVARIABLEX=y in first defconfig then it will apply to whole source code..!!

Comment: I followed your instructions but now it shows:
# CONFIG_VARIABLEX is not set
in .config even though I set it to y in the defconfig

Comment: have you registered it in any kconfig file? and make sure that kconfig is evaluted.